# file upload in adobe cq

Tags: file, upload, adobe, aem

I need to write a component that does **file upload (restrict the upload file types to PDF only).**

I have seen CQ has its own dialogs to upload files, but I am not sure, whether I could resuse them.

> Please let me know, if I could use out of the box xtypes "smartfile",
>   "fileuploadfield", "html5fileuploadfield", or "uploaddialogbutton"
>   with restriction to PDF files.
>
> OR  Do I need to write custom component extending one of the xtypes?

I appreciate all the help.

**EDIT**

```js
<div id='fi-form'></div>
<script>
  CQ.Ext.onReady( function(){


var card = new CQ.Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: 'fi-form',
    title: 'Example Wizard',
    layout:'card',
    activeItem: 0, // make sure the active item is set on the container config!
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
    defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        border:false
    },
    // the panels (or "cards") within the layout
    items: [{
        id: 'card-0',
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        emptyText: 'Select a PDF',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        name: 'photo-path'

    },{
        id: 'card-1',
        html: '<p>Step 2 of 3</p>'
    },{
        id: 'card-2',
        html: '<h1>Congratulations!</h1><p>Step 3 of 3 - Complete</p>'
    }]
});






  });

</script>
```

The following is the output

[image]

Could some one please tell me the what is this "Browse" button there ?

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about providing upload options in your dialog, then it is possible.

You can use the `html5smartfile` xtype and then add the `mimeTypes` property to specify the type of files that are allowed for uploading. You can also configure the `ddAccept` property to restrict the type of files that can be dragged and dropped from the content finder.

Sample configuration would be as follows

```
<upload jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
    fieldDescription="Accepts PDF files." 
    fieldLabel="Upload" 
    mimeTypes="application/pdf"
    mimeTypesDescription="PDF Files"
    name="./file"
    sizeLimit="100" 
    xtype="html5smartfile"/>
```

Additionally you can use the `sizeLimit` property to specify the maximum file size that can be uploaded and the `mimeTypesDescription` to specify the type of files allowed in the error message that pops up when a file with invalid mime type is uploaded.

Refer to [Widgets API](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartFile) to know more about available configurations.

Comment: Hello @Rakhi4110, Thank you for the help. I will try the smarfile xtype as you mentioned.  Just looking at the name property value, Can I store the file somewhere in dam path where intended. otherwise, it would store the files on the current page node content.